# How can I make a custom controller in strapi 4

Tags: strapi

I have problem with creation a custom route and a custom controller in strapi 4

I added screenshots and a description of what I did.

How can I make a custom controller in strapi 4?

I tried to follow strapi documentation but it didn't help

What did I do wrong?

I use the Postman for testing.

I made a collection todo and tested standard controllers and routes in the Postman, they worked well. I rewrote the logic of the method find in the standard controller and it also works fine.

I use this path  **{{strapi_url}}/api/todos?populate=user **(here I get all records this ralations by user and I rewrote the method find)

Then I made custom route and controller. The error occured when I tested my custom controller.

I have got message: `ForbiddenError`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjsVT.png)

I use this path: **{{strapi_url}}/api/todos/hello**
(strapi_url - varible path to may local project)

**This is my custom route**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOPX9.png)

**This is my custom controller**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lBCr.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/routes#implementation), when you create a route using `createCoreRouter` you generate automatically the core routes like find, findOne, etc...

To generate a custom route, you should use [this approach](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/routes#implementation). In this approach, you can make your `hello` path populating `path` property and map this route to your controller using `handler` property.

Comment: Hello Erme. I red article that you sent, but it is not clear how to make a custom controller with a custom route.
In my case I have todo "namespace". How should I place the custom controller "hello"?  
Is it right to make for the controller a special file (in my case hello.js) in the directory: api/todo/controllers/hello.jd?

Is it correct to place a custom route in api/todo/routes/hello.js 
What policy should I point to settings in the custom route? Can I set an empty array of policies?

Comment: my custom route:

Comment: const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = {
    routes: [
      {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/todos/hello",
        handler: "hello.index",
        config:{
            find: {
                auth: false,
                policies: [
                
                ]
            }
        }
      },
    ],
  };

Comment: my custom controller:

Comment: 'use strict';

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;


module.exports = createCoreController('api::todo.todo', ({ strapi }) => ({
    async index(ctx) {
            return 'hello';
    }
}));

Comment: It is not correct, because Postman returned ForbiddenError with status 403

Comment: Alex, in the handler you can put the complete controller name like: `api::todo.todo.hello`. You should also check if permissions to consume this route publicy are allowed in Strapi config.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super simple example of a custom route and controller.

You can see example project here: https://github.com/paulnotfromstrapi/strpai-custom-controller-route/tree/main/src/api/item

I have item collection type.

Since my controller is defined in the controllers/item.js file I am referencing it in the route as `item.customQuery`

Create a custom route.

```js
module.exports = {
  routes: [
    { // Path defined with an URL parameter
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/custom-query', 
      handler: 'item.customQuery',
    }
  ]
}
```

Create custom controller

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * item controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::item.item", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async customQuery(ctx) {
    const entry = await strapi.db.query('api::item.item').findOne();
    return entry;
    
  },
}));
```

Hope this example helps.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Also here is a post I wrote building a open ai chat bot with strapi project, it has example of creating your own route, service and controller.

https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-chat-gpt-clone-with-strapi-openai-langchain-and-nextjs